# Noise free image dataset

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, cnn, image

Presently, I am working on image denoising using CNNs. I am curious where I can find a noise-free image dataset?

I am looking for real-world images but not the dataset that belongs to MNIST.

Comment: Have you tried Kaggle
https://www.kaggle.com/

Comment: Yes I found few

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are *tons* of image datasets.  Wikipedia has a great list to get you started: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_datasets_for_machine-learning_research#Image_data

A few very popular datasets:

- [CIFAR-10 and CIFAR-100](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ekriz/cifar.html)
- [ImageNet](https://image-net.org/)
- [Open Images](https://opensource.google/projects/open-images-dataset)

Comment: Thank you for the links

Comment: Last question. are this noise-free image dataset?

Comment: yep, the images in these datasets are just regular images - no noise was added.